# Issue with bringing a 2d matrix into row echelon form in C using Gaussian Elimination

Tags: c, matrix

I am attempting to bring a matrix into row echelon form using C. The issue I am having is that occasionally, my code will allow ratio to have 0 as a denominator. The code snippet is as follows.

```html
double **identityMatrix = allocateMatrix(size, size);
double **modifiedMatrix = allocateMatrix(size,size);
identityMatrix = createIdentityMatrix(size);
modifiedMatrix = matrix;
double ratio = 0;
for(int curCol = 0; curCol < size; curCol++) //Bring to row echelon form
{
  for(int curRow = curCol +1; curRow < size; curRow++)
  {
    if(modifiedMatrix[curRow][curCol] != 0)
    {
     int tmp = curRow - 1;
      while(modifiedMatrix[tmp][curCol] == 0)
      {
         tmp--;
      }
      ratio = modifiedMatrix[curRow][curCol]/modifiedMatrix[tmp][curCol];
      modifiedMatrix = subtractRow(modifiedMatrix,curRow, tmp, size, ratio);
      identityMatrix = subtractRow(identityMatrix,curRow, tmp, size, ratio);
   }
  }
}
```

subtractRow is certainly implemented correctly as well as allocateMatrix. The matrix is always guaranteed to be invertible and square. matrix is passed in as a parameter. The issue is obviously with my 0 check, but I am not sure what is wrong with it. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: `double **identityMatrix = allocateMatrix(size, size);  .... 
identityMatrix = createIdentityMatrix(size);` over-writes the initialization of `identityMatrix`.

Comment: Allocate matrix is just to allocate the space for the 2d matrix since I am using a double pointer to represent a 2d matrix.

Comment: The why overwrite it with `identityMatrix = createIdentityMatrix(size);`?

Comment: @chux that’s actually a good point, thank you. I don’t believe that would be causing my issue of dividing by 0 however.

Comment: Notice `modifiedMatrix = matrix;` overwrites `double **modifiedMatrix = allocateMatrix(size,size);` too.

Comment: @chux thank you, I fixed that as well but my issue is persisting.

Comment: You can't compare floating point explicitly to 0 and expect it to "work" -- unless it's *exactly* 0. 
Before dividing A/B, I check to make sure B is not "too small" in A's magnitude. `if (fabs(A)*EPSILON < fabs(B)) C=A/B` where `EPSILON` is usually `DBL_EPSILON`

Comment: Also Gaussian elimination is not numerically stable unless you do some pivoting. Google "gaussian elimination numerical stability" and you should get some hits.

Comment: @MFisherKDX that makes a lot of sense, I forgot about that aspect of floating point. So instead of checking if it equals 0, I should use the code you provided?

Comment: @MFisherKDX my goal is to eventually get the inverse using Gaussian elimination. Will that effect this goal?

Comment: I've either used that method or the `fabs(x)> EPSILON` method. I don't have any rigorous reasons why either method would work though. It's been a long time since I studied Numerical Analysis.

Comment: As I understand, you can get the inverse using GE with pivoting and it is stable. Usually though, you don't write these functions yourself as there have been many years of research into making these numerical algorithms stable. There are some good linear algebra libraries in C if you want to go that route.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201696/gauss-elimination-for-nxm-matrix

Comment: @MFisherKDX unfortunately, I have to code the algorithm myself for my class, otherwise, I would not attempt to do it myself.

Comment: @MFisherKDX Your suggestion fixed my issue! Thank you so much! I definitely won't mess up with floating point comparisons again.

Comment: Interesting. Google for "numerical recipes in C second edition". You'll find a PDF you can download with solid and stable source code.

Answer (score -2):

I had been working on matrices lately, and the algorithm for converting a matrix to its row echelon was quite interesting.

You can view my code [here](http://github.com/bekingutkarsh/echelon)!

Happy coding.

Comment: Hi. Link only answers are frowned upon here. Please include the important parts of the code in a code block, and add a summary that hits the highlights. For reference, you can link external code, but if it becomes unavailable your answer will be of no use to anyone.